# Highcharts - set colour scheme option depending on number of series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Basically what I want to try and do is change the colour scheme of my theme of high charts depending on how many series there are. Is something like this possible to accomplish? Am i supposed to put this code inside the theme or inside each chart?

e.g.

```js
var colors = [];
var series = chart.series;

if (series == 2) {
  colors = ['blue', 'red'];
} else if (series == 3) {
  colors = ['blue', 'red', 'black'];
} else if (series == 4) {
  colors = ['blue', 'red', 'black', green];
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbo2o4Lm/

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do when you follow this order of operations:

1. Define your series
2. Adjust color array and apply theme
3. Create the chart

**Example code**:

```
var series = [{
  data: [1, 2]
}, {
  data: [2, 3]
}, {
  data: [1, 4]
}];

Highcharts.theme = {
  colors: (function() {
    var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange'];
    return colors.length <= series.length ? colors : colors.slice(0, series.length);
  })()
}

// Apply the theme
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: series
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/m2Lnh270/